# Check if the two given String are Isomorphic

Tags: java, string, algorithm, isomorphic

I am working on the LeetCode problem [**Isomorphic Strings**](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/question):

> Given two strings `s` and `t`, determine if they are isomorphic.
>
> Two strings `s` and `t` are isomorphic if the characters in `s` can be
> replaced to get `t`.
>
> All occurrences of a character must be replaced with another character
> while preserving the order of characters. No two characters may map to
> the same character, but a character may map to itself.
>
> *Example 1:*
>
> ```
> Input: s = "egg", t = "add"
> Output: true
> ```
>
> *Example 2:*
>
> ```
> Input: s = "foo", t = "bar"
> Output: false
> ```
>
> *Example 3:*
>
> ```
> Input: s = "paper", t = "title"
> Output: true
> ```
>
> ***Constraints:***
>
> - `1 <= s.length <= 5 * 104`
> - t.length == s.length
> - `s` and `t` consist of any valid ascii character.

I have most of the tests working correctly I am just failing some tests.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.nio.charset.*;

class Solution {

    public static boolean isIsomorphic(String s, String t) {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        t = t.toLowerCase();
        int matchCount1 = 0;
        int matchCount2 = 0;
        matchCount1 = checkMatching(s);
        matchCount2 = checkMatching(t);
        System.out.print(matchCount1);
        System.out.print(matchCount2);
        return matchCount1 == matchCount2;
    }

    public static int checkMatching(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { // s.length == 4
            char current = s.charAt(i); // current = 'p'
            j += 1;
            while (j < s.length() - 1) {
                if (current == s.charAt(j)) { // if p != a
                    count += 1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    j++; // j == 2
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "paper";
        String t = "title";

        isIsomorphic(s, t);
    }
}
```

*Failing test:*

If the strings `s = "foo"` and `t = "bar"`, the counts for both return `0`, where the answer should be `1` and `0` as `"foo"` contains two `"o"` characters.

Any help would be appreciated as I feel like I'm one small change away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what this task required is to determine whether the two Strings have identical structure, i.e. if string `s` contains character `'a'` at indices `1, 3, 8`, we expect string `t` to have identical character (of whatever kind) at indices `1, 3, 8` and this character shouldn't be encountered anywhere else in the `t`. It this holds true for every character - the String are *isomorphic*.

We can find out it in a linear time **O(n)** by indexing positions of every character in a Map for both strings. It would be a map of type `Map<Character,List<Integer>>`, which associates a character with its indices.

And then we need to find out if all combinations indices of these strings match. For that, we can dump the *Values* of each Map into a `HashSet`, it would be a set of type `Set<List<Integer>>`. And compare these sets using `Set.equals()` (*reminder: two sets are equal if they contain the same elements, regardless of their order*).

That's how implementation might look like:

```
public static boolean isIsomorphic(String s, String t) {
    if (s.length() != t.length()) return false; // early kill, if length of these string is not equal they are not isomorphic
    
    String first = s.toLowerCase();
    String second = t.toLowerCase();
    
    Set<List<Integer>> positions1 = getPositions(first);
    Set<List<Integer>> positions2 = getPositions(second);
    
    return positions1.equals(positions2);
}

public static Set<List<Integer>> getPositions(String str) {
    
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> positionsByCharacter = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char next = str.charAt(i);
        
        positionsByCharacter
            .computeIfAbsent(next, k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(i);
    }
    return new HashSet<>(positionsByCharacter.values());
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isIsomorphic("egg", "add"));
    System.out.println(isIsomorphic("foo", "bar"));
    System.out.println(isIsomorphic("paper", "title"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just wondering, do you know if I am on the correct track with my solution? It passed 28/34 tests but maybe the way I am going about it is incorrect. Thanks again

Comment: @smalliebigs30 The idea of storing the information about the indices occupied by a particular character in a String using a single `int` variable is not viable (see the explanation at the beginning of the answer. You can't address this problem like that.