# how can i iterate through two HasMap at once, i want o compare the values of two hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

here is the half code im making for isomorphic strings,

```
    public boolean isIsomorphic(String s, String t) {
        String[] ss=s.split("");
        String[] tt=t.split("");
        HashMap<String, Integer> smap=new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> tmap=new HashMap<>();
        int tint,sint;
        for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++){
            if(!smap.containsKey(ss[i])){
                smap.put(ss[i], 1);
            }else{
                sint=smap.get(ss[i]);
                smap.put(ss[i], sint++);
            }
        }
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<tt.length;i++){
            if(!tmap.containsKey(tt[i])){
                tmap.put(tt[i], 1);
            }else{
                tint=tmap.get(tt[i]);
                tmap.put(tt[i], tint++);
            }
        }
//below space to iterate and check if both hashmap values are sequentially 
    }
```

below is the solution i found ,i was about to use this logic but i cant compare two hashmaps, as both have different keys...
here all keys from both hashmaps are different, and values sequence wise might be same, thats all i wanna check...if all values are sequentially same or equal.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     String key = entry.getKey();
     Object value = entry.getValue();
     // ... 
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you want, even the code won't compile (`HashMap<String><String> `). Please review and post all code, then explain what you want and what you get, better with an example of data.

Comment: What you seem to be describing makes no sense.  If you do not intend to take the keys into account, then there is no meaningful sense in which you could be comparing the two maps.    You could conceivably compare their value collections, but that is not well characterized as comparing the maps themselves.

Comment: Note also that `HashMap` does not have a predictable iteration order, and neither does its value collection.  In this context, "*i wanna check...if all values are sequentially same or equal*" is nonsense.  There is no sequence you can safely rely on, unless impose one externally.  Even `SortedMap` implementations, which do have a predictable iteration order, are ordered according to their *keys*, not their values.

Comment: Related programming challenge / practice page: [LeetCode 205](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/description/)

Comment: Have you searched for related questions here? Does the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763156/check-if-the-two-given-string-are-isomorphic) help?

Comment: Off-topic,  programming tip:  **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.  You have two sections of code that are the same, except for the names of the variables. Consider writing that code in a method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Java solution [HERE](https://www.techiedelight.com/isomorphic-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to address the problem you asked: How might the contents of two `HashMap` Objects be compered. This might or might not solve the problem of verifying two `String` Objects are isomorphic.

Before addressing your question, I'd like to go off-topic:

I'd like to expand on a comment I made: Don't Repeat Yourself.  In the code shown in your question, you have two sections that load a `Map`, one section for each `String` parameter. You could reduce this to a method, and call it twice. Here is code similar to yours, but as a method:

```
public static LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> loadMap (String str) {
        LinkedHashMap <Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap <> ();
        char ss;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            ss = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i));
            if(!map.containsKey(ss)){
                map.put(ss, 1);
            }else{
                count=map.get(ss);
                map.put(ss, count++);
            }
        }     
        System.out.println (mapToString (map));
        return map;
    }
```

- This code uses a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` instead of `HashMap<String, Integer>`.
- This code converts uppercase characters to lowercase. However, this is probably *not desirable*, if I understand the instructions at [LeetCode 205](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/description/) properly.
- I have no good reason for using `Character` instead of `String` as keys, nor for using the `charAt (int index)` method of `String` instead of an array. It's my preference.
- By the way, the [`String` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/String.html) offers a [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method.
- **The code contains a bug.** The bug is in the code in the original question, and I preserved it in creating this method. I encourage you to find and fix the bug.
- Note that once you find the bug, in your original code, you will have to fix it twice. Using this method, and calling it twice, you will have to fix it  once. This is one of the advantages of "Don't Repeat Yourself".
- For debugging and testing, you might find the overloaded [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString()) in the [`AbstractMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.html) useful.

**Now, to address the question:**

You can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#entrySet()).  A Linked Hash Map is a map that also has a doubly linked list. The linked list maintains the entries in insertion order.

Although you want to iterate through the contents of the `Map` Objects, the `LinkedHashMap` API doe not offer a `get(int index)` or other method that supports iteration using a `for` loop. Neither does it directly offer an `iterator` method.

But, it does offer these methods:

- `public Set<Map.Entry<K,​V>> entrySet()`
- `public Set<K> keySet()`
- `public Collection<V> values()`

Note that a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Set.html) is a type of [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Collection.html). And a `Collection` *is* [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html).

- These methods return `Collection` views of the `LinkedHashMap`.
- They don't copy the data from the `Map` to a `new Set` or `new Collection` Object.
- They allow you to treat the `Map` as a `Set` or `Collection`.
- Think of them as wrappers for your `Map` Objects.

Now that you know those methods exist, and can find the API documentation, how you want to use them is up to you. Here is one way, but it is in keeping with using `Map<Character, Integer>`:

```
public static boolean isIsomorphic(String s, String t) {      
        if (s.length() != t.length()) { return false; }
        LinkedHashMap <Character, Integer> smap = loadMap (s);
        LinkedHashMap <Character, Integer> tmap = loadMap (t);
        if (smap.size() != tmap.size()) { return false; }      
        Collection<Integer> tValues = tmap.values();
        Collection<Integer> sValues = smap.values ();
        List<Integer> tList = new ArrayList<> ();
        tList.addAll(tValues);
        List<Integer> sList = new ArrayList<> ();
        sList.addAll (sValues);
        return sList.equals(tList);
    }
```

**Note:** *I addressed only the question of sequentially comparing contents of a pair of `HashMaps`.* If my understanding of the Isomorphic Strings problem is correct, this code will produce false positives. That is, it may identify a pair of `Strings` as isomorphic when they are not strictly isomorphic. I'll leave it to you to figure out why, to find an example of false positives.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! Your explanation and suggestions have been incredibly helpful in guiding me through the process of comparing HashMaps . i appreciate the effort you put into providing such thorough insights. thanks again...

Comment: @Sami3160  If this answer addresses your question you should consider accepting it (you can only accept one answer).  Just click on the check mark next to the answer.  When you get at least 15 rep you can also upvote it too.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use one map and a set to determine if they are isomorphic.

- first check the lengths of the strings as they should be the same.
- if not, they cannot be isomorphic as at least one char in one string would not map to the same (or any character) in the other string.
- if the are the same length, the use a set to contain all the mappings of a given character.  If any set exceeds length of 1, then the strings are not isomorphic since more than one mapping for a given character exists.

```
   public static boolean isIsomorphic(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
           String c = s1.substring(i,i+1);
           map.computeIfAbsent(c, v-> new HashSet<>()).add(s2.substring(i,i+1));
           if (map.get(c).size() > 1) {
               return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i see my code would tons of errors...well, ill follow your approach, didnt know, using hashmap the function would be this small, thanks